# Incremental build in Nsight Eclipse Edition

Tags: makefile, nsight, incremental-build

I have a project created in "Nsight Eclipse Edition". When i run Debug from the Nsight editor it works well, i.e., if only selected few files are modified Nsight performs -- "Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project".
But if the same project when i run from the commandLine from the ../Debug folder using the command "make" -- it always returns same output

~/cuda-workspace/MyProject/Debug$ make
make: `src/core_system/math/Gimplex/simplex.o' is up to date.

--and If i delete the file simplex.o from the folder and perform "make" again then Nsight builds only the simplex.cu file, though there were other modified files in MyProject.

My Current inefficient solution is I do a "make clean" and then "make".
Can anybody help me? What should I do to convert my makefile to obtain an incremental build even from the commandLine? ---below appending my makefile and .mk files

```
my file-- "makefile"   ################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include src/core_system/symbolic_states/subdir.mk
-include src/core_system/math/subdir.mk
-include src/core_system/math/Gimplex/subdir.mk
-include src/application/subdir.mk

--- missing include code -----

-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(CU_DEPS)),)
-include $(CU_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: MyProject

# Tool invocations
MyProject: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: NVCC Linker'
    /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc --cudart static -L/usr/local/lib --relocatable-device-code=false -gencode arch=compute_11,code=compute_11 -gencode arch=compute_12,code=compute_12 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_12,code=sm_12 -link -o  "MyProject" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(CU_DEPS)$(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) MyProject
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets



my file-- "sources.mk"   
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

O_SRCS := 
CPP_SRCS := 
C_UPPER_SRCS := 
C_SRCS := 
S_UPPER_SRCS := 
OBJ_SRCS := 
CU_SRCS := 
ASM_SRCS := 
CXX_SRCS := 
C++_SRCS := 
CC_SRCS := 
CU_DEPS := 
OBJS := 
C++_DEPS := 
C_DEPS := 
CC_DEPS := 
CPP_DEPS := 
EXECUTABLES := 
CXX_DEPS := 
C_UPPER_DEPS := 

# Every subdirectory with source files must be described here
SUBDIRS := \
src/core_system/symbolic_states \
src/core_system/math \
src/core_system/math/Gimplex \
--some more missing lines ----



Appending for sample two subdir.mk file from different folder

1) my file --"Debug/src/core_system/symbolic_states/subdir.mk"
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
CPP_SRCS += \
../src/core_system/symbolic_states/symbolic_states.cpp 

OBJS += \
./src/core_system/symbolic_states/symbolic_states.o 

CPP_DEPS += \
./src/core_system/symbolic_states/symbolic_states.d 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
src/core_system/symbolic_states/%.o: ../src/core_system/symbolic_states/%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: NVCC Compiler'
    /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -I"/home/amit/cuda-workspace/MyProject/src" -I/usr/local/include -G -g -O3 -Xcompiler -fopenmp -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_12,code=sm_12  -odir "src/core_system/symbolic_states" -M -o "$(@:%.o=%.d)" "$<"
    /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -I"/home/amit/cuda-workspace/MyProject/src" -I/usr/local/include -G -g -O3 -Xcompiler -fopenmp --compile  -x c++ -o  "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

2) my file --"Debug/src/core_system/math/Gimplex/subdir.mk"
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
CU_SRCS += \
../src/core_system/math/Gimplex/simplex.cu 

CU_DEPS += \
./src/core_system/math/Gimplex/simplex.d 

OBJS += \
./src/core_system/math/Gimplex/simplex.o 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
src/core_system/math/Gimplex/%.o: ../src/core_system/math/Gimplex/%.cu
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: NVCC Compiler'
    /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -I"/home/amit/cuda-workspace/MyProject/src" -I/opt/gurobi600/linux64/include -I/usr/local/include -G -g -O3 -Xcompiler -fopenmp -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_12,code=sm_12  -odir "src/core_system/math/Gimplex" -M -o "$(@:%.o=%.d)" "$<"
    /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -I"/home/amit/cuda-workspace/MyProject/src" -I/opt/gurobi600/linux64/include -I/usr/local/include -G -g -O3 -Xcompiler -fopenmp --compile --relocatable-device-code=false -gencode arch=compute_11,code=compute_11 -gencode arch=compute_12,code=compute_12 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_12,code=sm_12  -x cu -o  "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```